# npx @shopware-pwa/cli@canary init Error: Command failed: yarn install

Tags: yarnpkg, shopware

Im trying to install shopware with shopware-pwa. I have a shopware instance running with docker and trying to install the shopware-pwa. I followed this [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Z5eQ7vXD85k). I created a `docker-compose.yml` and run `docker-compose up`. Then I added SwagShopwarePWA as Plugin inside the shopware ui and run `npx @shopware-pwa/cli@canary init` inside the project `root/pwa/`.
Yarn is up to date.

my docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3"

services:
  shopware:
    image: dockware/dev:6.4.0.0
    container_name: shopware
    ports:
      - 80:80
    volumes:
      - "db_volume:/var/lib/mysql"
      - "shop_volume:/var/www/html"
    networks:
      - web
    environment:
      - XDEBUG_ENABLED=0

volumes:
  db_volume:
    driver: local
  shop_volume:
    driver: local

networks:
  web:
    external: false
```

This is my output.

> npx @shopware-pwa/cli@canary init ✔ Shopware instance address: ·
> http://localhost ✔ Shopware instance access token: ·
> MyToken ✔ PWA plugin is installed ✔ Preparing Nuxt
> project ⠙ [CLI > init] Updating configuration for v:
> ^1.6.2-canary.1723/Users/hallodri/.npm/_npx/a4ede7f2a8d2d585/node_modules/gluegun/build/index.js:15
> throw up;
> ^
>
> Error: Command failed: yarn install
>
> ```
> at ChildProcess.exithandler (node:child_process:419:12)
> at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:512:28)
> at maybeClose (node:internal/child_process:1098:16)
> at ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:304:5) {   code: 1,   killed: false,   signal: null,   cmd: 'yarn install',
> ```
>
> stdout: '➤ YN0000: ┌ Resolution step\n' +
> '➤ YN0061: │ urix@npm:0.1.0 is deprecated: Please see [https://github.com/lydell/urix#deprecated\n'](https://github.com/lydell/urix#deprecated%5Cn%27) +
> '➤ YN0061: │ source-map-resolve@npm:0.5.3 is deprecated: See [https://github.com/lydell/source-map-resolve#deprecated\n'](https://github.com/lydell/source-map-resolve#deprecated%5Cn%27) +
> '➤ YN0061: │ core-js@npm:2.6.12 is deprecated: core-js@<3.23.3 is no longer maintained and not recommended for usage due to the number
> of issues. Because of the V8 engine whims, feature detection in old
> core-js versions could cause a slowdown up to 100x even if nothing is
> polyfilled. Some versions have web compatibility issues. Please,
> upgrade your dependencies to the actual version of core-js.\n' +
> '➤ YN0032: │ node-addon-api@npm:1.7.2: Implicit dependencies on node-gyp are discouraged\n' +
> '➤ YN0032: │ fsevents@npm:2.3.2: Implicit dependencies on node-gyp are discouraged\n' +
> '➤ YN0061: │ source-map-url@npm:0.4.1 is deprecated: See [https://github.com/lydell/source-map-url#deprecated\n'](https://github.com/lydell/source-map-url#deprecated%5Cn%27) +
> '➤ YN0061: │ resolve-url@npm:0.2.1 is deprecated: [https://github.com/lydell/resolve-url#deprecated\n'](https://github.com/lydell/resolve-url#deprecated%5Cn%27) +
> '➤ YN0061: │ @npmcli/move-file@npm:1.1.2 is deprecated: This functionality has been moved to @npmcli/fs\n' +
> '➤ YN0061: │ chokidar@npm:2.1.8 is deprecated: Chokidar 2 does not receive security updates since 2019. Upgrade to chokidar 3 with 15x
> fewer dependencies\n' +
> '➤ YN0061: │ fsevents@npm:1.2.13 is deprecated: fsevents 1 will break on node v14+ and could be using insecure binaries. Upgrade to
> fsevents 2.\n' +
> '➤ YN0032: │ nan@npm:2.17.0: Implicit dependencies on node-gyp are discouraged\n' +
> '➤ YN0061: │ @npmcli/move-file@npm:2.0.1 is deprecated: This functionality has been moved to @npmcli/fs\n' +
> '➤ YN0061: │ querystring@npm:0.2.0 is deprecated: The querystring API is considered Legacy. new code should use the URLSearchParams API
> instead.\n' +
> '➤ YN0032: │ evp_bytestokey@npm:1.0.3: Implicit dependencies on node-gyp are discouraged\n' +
> '➤ YN0061: │ stable@npm:0.1.8 is deprecated: Modern JS already guarantees Array#sort() is a stable sort, so this library is
> deprecated. See the compatibility table on MDN:
> [https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort#browser_compatibility\n'](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort#browser_compatibility%5Cn%27)
> +
> '➤ YN0061: │ request@npm:2.88.2 is deprecated: request has been deprecated, see [https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142\n'](https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142%5Cn%27) +
> '➤ YN0061: │ har-validator@npm:5.1.5 is deprecated: this library is no longer supported\n' +
> '➤ YN0061: │ uuid@npm:3.4.0 is deprecated: Please upgrade  to version 7 or higher.  Older versions may use Math.random() in certain
> circumstances, which is known to be problematic.  See
> https://v8.dev/blog/math-random for details.\n' +
> "➤ YN0002: │ @nuxt/typescript-build@npm:2.1.0 [3c4ef] doesn't provide webpack (p05fde), requested by
> fork-ts-checker-webpack-plugin\n" +
> "➤ YN0002: │ @nuxt/typescript-build@npm:2.1.0 [3c4ef] doesn't provide webpack (pcfc7e), requested by ts-loader\n" +
> "➤ YN0002: │ @shopware-pwa/default-theme@npm:1.6.2-canary.1723 [3c4ef] doesn't provide webpack (p0df6b), requested by sass-loader\n"
> +
> "➤ YN0002: │ @shopware-pwa/nuxt-module@npm:1.6.2-canary.1723 doesn't provide @babel/core (p014b8), requested by
> @babel/plugin-proposal-nullish-coalescing-operator\n" +
> "➤ YN0002: │ @shopware-pwa/nuxt-module@npm:1.6.2-canary.1723 doesn't provide @babel/core (pd6281), requested by
> @babel/plugin-proposal-optional-chaining\n" +
> "➤ YN0002: │ @shopware-pwa/nuxt-module@npm:1.6.2-canary.1723 doesn't provide core-js (p0dbb3), requested by
> @shopware-pwa/default-theme\n" +
> "➤ YN0002: │ @shopware-pwa/nuxt-module@npm:1.6.2-canary.1723 doesn't provide css-loader (pe21c9), requested by vue-loader\n" +
> "➤ YN0002: │ @shopware-pwa/nuxt-module@npm:1.6.2-canary.1723 doesn't provide nuxt (pece12), requested by
> @shopware-pwa/default-theme\n" +
> "➤ YN0002: │ @shopware-pwa/nuxt-module@npm:1.6.2-canary.1723 doesn't provide vue (p26fbb), requested by
> @shopware-pwa/composables\n" +
> "➤ YN0002: │ @shopware-pwa/nuxt-module@npm:1.6.2-canary.1723 doesn't provide vue (p9cb32), requested by
> @shopware-pwa/default-theme\n" +
> "➤ YN0002: │ @shopware-pwa/nuxt-module@npm:1.6.2-canary.1723 doesn't provide vue (pb97f8), requested by vue-router\n" +
> "➤ YN0002: │ @shopware-pwa/nuxt-module@npm:1.6.2-canary.1723 doesn't provide webpack (pc2e10), requested by vue-loader\n" +
> "➤ YN0002: │ @storefront-ui/vue@npm:0.13.2 doesn't provide @types/leaflet (p11bb0), requested by vue2-leaflet\n" +
> "➤ YN0002: │ @storefront-ui/vue@npm:0.13.2 doesn't provide webpack (p07de0), requested by sass-loader\n" +
> "➤ YN0002: │ nuxt@npm:2.16.3 doesn't provide consola (p71ad6), requested by @nuxt/components\n" +
> "➤ YN0002: │ shopware-pwa-project@workspace:. doesn't provide @babel/core (p70df4), requested by babel-core\n" +
> "➤ YN0002: │ shopware-pwa-project@workspace:. doesn't provide @babel/core (p473dc), requested by babel-jest\n" +
> "➤ YN0002: │ shopware-pwa-project@workspace:. doesn't provide eslint (pd54c2), requested by eslint-config-prettier\n" +
> "➤ YN0002: │ shopware-pwa-project@workspace:. doesn't provide eslint (p803b2), requested by eslint-plugin-prettier\n" +
> "➤ YN0002: │ shopware-pwa-project@workspace:. doesn't provide vue (p1c5d8), requested by @vue/composition-api\n" +
> "➤ YN0002: │ shopware-pwa-project@workspace:. doesn't provide vue (pd023f), requested by @vue/test-utils\n" +
> "➤ YN0002: │ shopware-pwa-project@workspace:. doesn't provide vue (p70e03), requested by @vuelidate/core\n" +
> "➤ YN0002: │ shopware-pwa-project@workspace:. doesn't provide vue (p55171), requested by @vuelidate/validators\n" +
> "➤ YN0002: │ shopware-pwa-project@workspace:. doesn't provide vue (p2c366), requested by vue-jest\n" +
> "➤ YN0002: │ shopware-pwa-project@workspace:. doesn't provide vue-template-compiler (p768f9), requested by vue-jest\n" +
> '➤ YN0000: │ Some peer dependencies are incorrectly met; run yarn explain peer-requirements  for details, where  is the
> six-letter p-prefixed code\n' +
> '➤ YN0000: └ Completed in 41s 831ms\n' +
> '➤ YN0000: ┌ Fetch step\n' +
> "➤ YN0013: │ @ampproject/remapping@npm:2.2.1 can't be found in the cache and will be fetched from the remote registry\n" +
> "➤ YN0013: │ @babel/code-frame@npm:7.21.4 can't be found in the cache and will be fetched from the remote registry\n" +
> "➤ YN0013: │ @babel/compat-data@npm:7.21.4 can't be found in the cache and will be fetched from the remote registry\n" +
> "➤ YN0013: │ @babel/core@npm:7.21.4 can't be found in the cache and will be fetched from the remote registry\n" +
> "➤ YN0013: │ @babel/generator@npm:7.21.4 can't be found in the cache and will be fetched from the remote registry\n" +
> "➤ YN0013: │ @babel/code-frame@npm:7.21.4 can't be found in the cache and will be fetched from the remote registry\n" +
> "➤ YN0013: │ @babel/compat-data@npm:7.21.4 can't be found in the cache and will be fetched from the remote registry\n" +
> "➤ YN0013: │ @babel/core@npm:7.21.4 can't be found in the cache and will be fetched from the remote registry\n" +
> "➤ YN0013: │ @babel/generator@npm:7.21.4 can't be found in the cache and will be fetched from the remote registry\n" +
> "➤ YN0013: │ @babel/helper-annotate-as-pure@npm:7.18.6 can't be found in the cache and will be fetched from the remote registry\n" +
> "➤ YN0013: │ @babel/compat-data@npm:7.21.4 can't be found in the cache and will be fetched from the remote registry\n" +
> "➤ YN0013: │ @babel/core@npm:7.21.4 can't be found in the cache and will be fetched from the remote registry\n" +
> "➤ YN0013: │ @babel/generator@npm:7.21.4 can't be found in the cache and will be fetched from the remote registry\n" +
> "➤ YN0013: │ @babel/helper-annotate-as-pure@npm:7.18.6 can't be found in the cache and will be fetched from the remote registry\n" +
> "➤ YN0013: │ @babel/helper-builder-binary-assignment-operator-visitor@npm:7.18.9
> can't be found in the cache and will be fetched from the remote
> registry\n" +
> "➤ YN0013: │ @babel/core@npm:7.21.4 can't be found in the cache and will be fetched from the remote registry\n" +
> "➤ YN0013: │ @babel/generator@npm:7.21.4 can't be found in the cache and will be fetched from the remote registry\n" +
> "➤ YN0013: │ @babel/helper-annotate-as-pure@npm:7.18.6 can't be found in the cache and will be fetched from the remote registry\n" +
> "➤ YN0013: │ @babel/helper-builder-binary-assignment-operator-visitor@npm:7.18.9
> can't be found in the cache and will be fetched from the remote
> registry\n" +
> "➤ YN0013: │ @babel/helper-compilation-targets@npm:7.21.4 can't be found in the cache and will be fetched from the remote registry\n" +
> "➤ YN0013: │ @babel/generator@npm:7.21.4 can't be found in the cache and will be fetched from the remote registry\n" +
> "➤ YN0013: │ @babel/helper-annotate-as-pure@npm:7.18.6 can't be found in the cache and will be fetched from the remote registry\n" +
> "➤ YN0013: │ @babel/helper-builder-binary-assignment-operator-visitor@npm:7.18.9
> can't be found in the cache and will be fetched from the remote
> registry\n" +
> "➤ YN0013: │ @babel/helper-compilation-targets@npm:7.21.4 can't be found in the cache and will be fetched from the remote registry\n" +
> "➤ YN0013: │ @babel/helper-create-class-features-plugin@npm:7.21.4 can't be found in the cache and will be fetched from the remote
> registry\n" +
> "➤ YN0013: │ @babel/helper-annotate-as-pure@npm:7.18.6 can't be found in the cache and will be fetched from the remote registry\n" +
> "➤ YN0013: │ @babel/helper-builder-binary-assignment-operator-visitor@npm:7.18.9
> can't be found in the cache and will be fetched from the remote
> registry\n" +
> "➤ YN0013: │ @babel/helper-compilation-targets@npm:7.21.4 can't be found in the cache and will be fetched from the remote registry\n" +
> "➤ YN0013: │ @babel/helper-create-class-features-plugin@npm:7.21.4 can't be found in the cache and will be fetched from the remote
> registry\n" +
> "➤ YN0013: │ @babel/helper-create-regexp-features-plugin@npm:7.21.4 can't be found
> in the cache and will be fetched from the remote registry\n" +
> "➤ YN0013: │ @babel/helper-builder-binary-assignment-operator-visitor@npm:7.18.9
> can't be found in the cache and will be fetched from the remote
> registry\n" +
> "➤ YN0013: │ @babel/helper-compilation-targets@npm:7.21.4 can't be found in the cache and will be fetched from the remote registry\n" +
> "➤ YN0013: │ @babel/helper-create-class-features-plugin@npm:7.21.4 can't be found in the cache and will be fetched from the remote
> registry\n" +
> "➤ YN0013: │ @babel/helper-create-regexp-features-plugin@npm:7.21.4 can't be found
> in the cache and will be fetched from t"... 809823 more characters,
> stderr: '' }
>
> Node.js v19.7.0

Any help appreaciated!